# making a jface wizard come to the start on hitting a button/link

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have a jface Wizard, I have a link on the bottom of the wizard and when I click the link the wizard should start a fresh from the start and all the previous selections must go ,It should work as if i'm opening a new wizard again with no selections remaining from current selections.

I've tried opening the first page on the widget selection but it doesn't seem to work, I'm unable to hit the next button

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `WizardPage` you could do something like:

```java
IWizard wizard = getWizard();

IWizardPage page = wizard.getPage("page name");

IWizardContainer container = wizard.getContainer();

container.showPage(page);
```

`"page name"` is the name of the wizard page you specified in its Constructor.

This will show the particular page, you will need to clear the contents in the `setVisible` method.

Comment: I didn't get the page name that we are supposed to pass , do  I need to pass the object of wizard page-1 that I have created or is it something else, I've tried with sending the object of wiz-page1 I'm getting a null value

Comment: Thanks Greg, that was really helpful, I figured it out, it's the String argument that you send to the wizard page right...

Comment: Yes, the first argument of the WizardPage constructor.